# How do I change the font size of an echo?

Tags: html, css, font-size

I need to know how to change the font size of the output of an echo. I already have a different font colour in the code, and it's making it more complicated for a noob like me. The echo should be in black and a size like 150%. Please write out the full code for it, and if anyone could teach me how it could be done would really help me out. Thanks.

```
<?php
srand (microtime()*10000);
$f_contents = file ("secretnet.txt");
$line = $f_contents[array_rand ($f_contents)];
echo "<font color='black'>$line</font>";
?>
```

Comment: use CSS instead. that tag's deprecated. Google "CSS font size color".

Comment: This is HTML / CSS - It's one of the most basic things, do some research, find some tutorials and guides and follow them, SO is **NOT** here to provide code or here to teach you.

Comment: Google: set font size in html noob tutorial :-)

Comment: Yes. This is the only code I can use for what I am doing, please show me how I would do it, even if it is css.

Comment: *"Please write out the full code for it"* - Is ***hell no*** an acceptable "answer"?

Comment: @Fred-ii- In my world. _**hell yes**_

Comment: @Epodax ah, the underscores; *nice effect* ;-)

Comment: @Epodax you mean ***_hell yes_*** ?

Comment: @Epodax use 3x *** text followed by 3x ***

Comment: @Fred-ii- ***very nice***

Comment: @Epodax *`et voilà`*

Comment: this question received an upvote? *wow*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your php file:

```
<?php
srand (microtime()*10000);
$f_contents = file ("secretnet.txt");
$line = $f_contents[array_rand ($f_contents)];
echo "<div class='awesomeText'>$line</div>";
?>
```

In your file: style.css which need to be included as a linked resource on top of your page.

```
.awesomeText {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 150%;
}
```

Here is a quick sample: http://jsfiddle.net/qro9r54t/

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, but like others have mentioned using CSS ( with a style sheet preferably ) instead would be ideal.

```
<?php
srand (microtime()*10000);
$f_contents = file ("secretnet.txt");
$line = $f_contents[array_rand ($f_contents)];
echo "<div style='font-size:150%; color:#000000'>" .  $line . "</div>";
?>
```

It'd look something like this if you're using a style sheet. If you need help with those I'd recommend posting in the CSS section of the site.

```
<?php
srand (microtime()*10000);
$f_contents = file ("secretnet.txt");
$line = $f_contents[array_rand ($f_contents)];
echo "<div class='your_class_name_here'>" .  $line . "</div>";
?>
```

Comment: *"The echo should be in black and a size like 150%"*

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can change the rest.

Comment: But *you are* using CSS???

Comment: `color=black` that is a syntax error *ain't it Sam?* @JayBlanchard

Comment: Well, I mean use a style sheet to control this instead of embedding the styles inside the div.

Comment: I'd edit this myself to correct the fact that you're using an equals sign in the CSS instead of a colon, but that's less than the required 6 character edit.

Comment: @Rodney To be honest, I just started learning all this. Could you explain how I would control the echo through CSS? Sorry xD

Comment: @Rodney your answer is still incorrect. It contains a syntax error. I could fix it, but that isn't MY job.

Comment: for crying outloud, I DO have to do everything. *Kids today*.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks, I guess.

Comment: @Rulen24 I'll update it for you so you can see.

Comment: You're welcome Rodney. I have no idea why you didn't edit it in the first place, when I signaled it earlier, and twice. I think that 20 years of HTML/CSS experience between some of the guys here know what they're talking about. I remember when CSS's introduction was frowned upon by many and said it wouldn't last... well... it did. ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Just getting my feet wet with this site, forgive the growing pains.